# php error log show UTC time zone instead of ICT

Tags: php

I have set date.time.zone = "Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh" in my php.ini

System time is Thu Aug 15 14:45:26 **ICT** 2013

Buy php error log show

[15-Aug-2013 07:44:04 **UTC**] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/

Did i miss configuration anywhere ?

Comment: I'm late to this question, but anyway let me point out for future reference that you seem to have an extra dot there. I think the correct setting is `date.timezone`

Answer (score 0):

Check [Bug #60723, error_log error time has changed to UTC ignoring default timezone](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60723)

PHP 5.3.23 is confirmed as patched for this error, but 5.4.14 for example seems not to be according to some reports although the patch is in the changelog of php 5.4.8.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45191, not fixed in my 5.4.4 (debian stable), but fixed in the dotdeb 5.4.17 version.